# same ng-repeat data in multiple places in the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to output two lists with data from the same `ng-repeat` in different parts of the page. For example:

```
// list # 1
<ul ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
    <li ng-bind="item.name"></li>
</ul>

// list # 2
<ul ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
    <li ng-bind="item.color"></li>
</ul>
```

Instead of using multiple instances of the same `ng-repeat`, is there a way to use data from the first `ng-repeat` instance in `list # 2`?

Comment: Can you use jquery instead of angular js?

Comment: no, I need to use angular in there.

Comment: Is there any way to store globally in page?

Comment: I don't mind using multiple instances of the same `ng-repeat` I though there was optimized angular way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

What's the reason for wanting to do it?  I doubt there would be any noticable performance increase so I don't see an issue with using the ng-repeat again (and again, and again) for the same data.

Unless you have some other reason for not wanting to do it that way, I would say that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a way to optimize in the way that you describe above.  However, if your lists are going to be long you can run into performance issues.  The ng-repeats each set up an implicit watcher because of the two way data binding.  You can run into performance issues when your page has a large amount of data and lots of watchers.  If your list data doesn't need to be dynamic - ie, change with a selection or something - I'd recommend using one time bindings.  They're available out of the box with [Angular 1.3](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) and there's a third party package that accomplishes the same thing in Angular 1.2.  If you're concerned about performance with your ng-repeats (which sounds like what you're really getting at in your question) it's worth implementing one time bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Computationally speaking, making two loops with one operation each or one loop with two operations is the same thing (if not for some overhead).
Probably you could do a loop that prints all the `<li>` elements and then moves some to another `<ul>` but that would probably be more complex actually (and probably would require to be implemented not in "the angular way").

I doubt there is a more optimized way and if there was it won't be by much